Как внести корректировки в пост REST API
Есть сайт на WordPress, с помощью REST API я публикую на нем статьи, пример:
POST http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?title=Заголовок&slug=my-post&content=Девушка очень стройнаяstatus=publish
Задача не заменить текст на новый, а дописать к к основному, то есть внести корректировки, как это сделать? Я попробовал так:
POST http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?content=и красивая
Но так текст просто заменяется, а не добавляется
